# big data load in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, informatica

I came across weird constraint, want to hear if anyone has resolved this issue.

Problem statement: load data in salesforce from outside. volume of data is 1 million record in a burst, every 3 hrs.

my source orchestration tool (NiFi) is capable of making this many REST API, but salesforce has asked not to use REST with this much throughput. I am not sure if its a limit of salesforce or product team has created a artificial ceiling.

they have suggested use dataloader, which seems to be a batch loader for salesforce, but it is not that fast either. also it has different issues. I cant trigger dataloader, when i get the data, so not that helpful either.

Long time back i have used Informatica to connect to salesforce, and we used to pass similar amount of data, and with no issue. Can someone answer how informatica connector has solved this bottleneck issue ?what does it use underneath?

also any other way to push this much data to salesforce?

Comment: they use the bulk api https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: rethink your use case. Rewrite your app to use different mechanism of connecting to SF.

Long answer: Standard Salesforce API (SOAP or REST, doesn't matter) is synchronous. Request-response, job done. It's limited to 200 records max in one API call. Your volumes are better suited for bulk API. That one is REST-only (although it can accept XML, JSON or CSV), up to 10K records in one API call. The key difference is that it's asynchronous. You submit the job, you get back the job's id, you can check it (every 10 seconds? every minute?) "is it done yet? if it is - give me back my success/failure results". But every of these checks will of course consume 1 API call too. In meantime SF received a bunch of zipped files from you and will work on unzipping and processing them as fast as resources allow.

So (ignoring the initial `login` call) let's talk about limits. In sandboxes the 24h rolling limit of API calls is 5 million calls. Massive. In production it's 15K API calls + 1K per every full license user you have (sales cloud, service cloud) + you can buy more capacity... Or just go to Setup -> Company Information and check your limit.

let's say you have 5 users so 20K calls/day in production. In 24h at max capacity you'll be able to push 10K * 20K = 200M inserts/updates. Well, bit less because of login calls and checking the status and pulling down the results file but still - pretty good. If that's not enough - you have bigger problems ;) Using standard API would let you go 200 * 20K = mere 4M records.

SF support told you to use Data Loader because in DL it's just ticking a checkbox to use bulk API. You don't care that backend mechanism is different. You could even script Data Loader to run from commandline (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf chapter 4). Or if it's a Java application - just reuse the JAR file on top of which DL UI is built.

These might help too:

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/large-data-volumes/load-your-data
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk